# Elasticsearch in golang returns no results using olivere/elastic package

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I am trying to implement elasticsearch in my go application. I am using https://github.com/olivere/elastic library for go and elasticsearch is running in docker container.

I successfully connected to elasticsearch and create index, after that I tried to save data to elasticsearch that was also successful. I started getting problems when I was running queries

My mapping looks like this

```
    "mappings":{
        "item":{
            "properties":{
                "id":{
                    "type":"integer"
                },
                "title":{
                    "type":"text"
                },
                "description":{
                    "type":"text"
                },
                "userid":{
                    "type":"integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to query es by title like this and I get empty response.
If I Remove query from my Search() es lists all items saved.
I tried also combining with newBoolQuery and newMatchPhrase it was also returning empty response.

```
query := elastic.NewTermQuery("title", "Hello there")
searchResult, err := elasticClient.Search().
    Index("items").
    Query(query).
    Pretty(true).
    Do(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
return searchResult, nil
```

Response :

```
 {
    "id": 81,
    "message": "Search successfull",
    "data": {
        "took": 1,
        "_scroll_id": "",
        "hits": {
            "total": 0,
            "max_score": null,
            "hits": []
        },
        "suggest": null,
        "aggregations": null,
        "timed_out": false,
        "_shards": {
            "total": 1,
            "successful": 1,
            "failed": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should go with `NewMatchQuery` in your case, as said in docs for [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)

> Avoid using the term query for text fields.
>
> By default, Elasticsearch changes the values of text fields as part of
>   analysis. This can make finding exact matches for text field values
>   difficult.
>
> To search text field values, use the match query instead.

You didn't share sample documents you indexed and what are you trying to find, but something like below should help in your case

```
query := NewMatchQuery("title", "Hello there")
```

Hope that helps.